# How to sort a format by certain column?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sorting

i have a format like this:

```
user: "some_text"
```

i need to alphabetically sort the file by the `user`.The problem is when the user duplicates and i need to maintain the position of the `"some_text"`.
ex:

```
Jack: "Daniel has an apple"
Daniel: "No"
Daniel: "Jack is a morun"
Daniel: "Alfa and beta"
John: "Blah blah blah"
```

i tried `sort -t':' -k1,1` and i get this:

```
Daniel: "Alfa and beta"
Daniel: "Jack is a morun"
Daniel: "No"
Jack: "Daniel has an apple"
John: "Blah blah blah"
```

i need:

```
Daniel: "No"
Daniel: "Jack is a morun"
Daniel: "Alfa and beta"
Jack: "Daniel has an apple"
John: "Blah blah blah"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at GNU sort‘s option:

> `-s`: stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison

---

```
sort -s -t':' -k1,1 file
```

Output:

```
Daniel: "No"
Daniel: "Jack is a morun"
Daniel: "Alfa and beta"
Jack: "Daniel has an apple"
John: "Blah blah blah"
```